How to throw 404 Not Found Error along with 404 status code in NextJS 13 App Router from page.jsx?
I'm using async fetch request in page.tsx component similar to the below code
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'

const PostViewPage = async ({params}) => {
    const {slug} = params;
    const resData = await fetch(`/api/post/${slug}`); //slug is a dynamic value
    const postData = resData.json();
    if(postData){
        //rest code
    }else{
        notFound();
    }

    return (<>JSX Code</>)
}

If slug is not valid then it showing 404 Not Found page in browser.
But, the request Status Code getting 200 in POSTMAN.

I want to throw 404 Page Not Found Error along with 404 Status Code.
if any work around is there, Please guide me on this.

Hi, did you use some kind of loading.tsx in your app root layout ?

Yes, loading.tsx component added in root layout
if the server takes time to load content till that time I can see the loading Screen in the browser.

what is fetch api returns?

You can remove loading.tsx on the root layout

@cantdocpp Thanks for your suggestion,
while in R&D I got the reason just before your suggestion, It was because of the loading component, And I removed that component now it working fine.

Yes, that's why i asked you to remove the loading.tsx. Because the loading component causes that. It's a known issue among the next.js communities

I'll post an answer below, just in case someone else also needed it

Hi, @cantdocpp is there any way, Where I can show Loading Animation and I can get 404 status also?

Hi, you can try to create a /404 route and try to redirect an empty items to that route manually. Someone said that /404 route is special and it apply 404 status code automatically. Maybe that's the solution for now

To be fair, there's already a PR to fix this issue, but it still hasn't been approved and merged yet

It was caused by the loading.tsx file, especially at the root folder or app. this is a known issue in next.js for now.
The only suggestion is that you can try to removing the root loading.tsx file or suspense at root layout

If that's all the content of your page.tsx file, double check to be sure you're importing the notFound function into your file.
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
You also need to have a app/not-found.tsx in your root directory. This file renders a UI when the notFound function is thrown within a route segment.
Read more on the NEXT.js docs.

Hi @praizjosh
Already, I have added import on top of the page.
And I'm able to see the 404 Error Page.
The Main Issue is that Even a 404 Page,
request Status Code gets 200 in POSTMAN as you can see this screenshot
https://i.sstatic.net/cW6ooobg.png

@Mankesh Can you create a codepen for better understanding?
